# Lead Conversion - System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Tags: account, leads, lead-conversion

Facing this issue on production. On sandbox it is working fine.

Converting the lead to business account and contact but on production for few records it is failing.

Code for lead conversion.

```
{
    Database.LeadConvert leadConvert;
    leadConvert = new database.LeadConvert();
    leadConvert.setLeadId(leadId);
    leadConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
    leadConvert.setAccountId(mappedAccountId);
    leadConvert.setContactId(mappedContactId);
    LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
    leadConvert.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
    List<Database.LeadConvertResult> leadConversionResults = Database.convertLead( new list<database.LeadConvert>{leadConvert} );
    System.debug(leadConversionResults);
    Lead leadData = [select id, status from lead where id = :leadId limit 1];
    leadData.status = LEAD_CONVERT_STATUS_QUALIFIED;
    update leadData;
    System.debug(leadData);
```

MappedAccountData is like this after debug.

```
22:03:33:222 USER_DEBUG [150]|DEBUG|Account:{RecordTypeId=0121r00000071g2A1E, Name=Test, BusinessId__c=2832152-1, OwnerId=0051r24000At3eAAAR, Selected_Area__c=TestArea, NumberOfEmployees=1, Data_source__c=Test, AccountSource=Website, NumberOfEntrepreneurs__c=1, Id=0016900002YXQ36AAH}
```

Error Screenshot:

[image]

How it can be fixed? What is the problem it is working fine for many records on production but for few it is giving error?

Comment: seems that the 'Company' field is empty for the record you are trying to convert

Comment: Another possibility is https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cRaCQAU

Comment: I have the same problem like this https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cRaCQAU but when I removed         leadConvert.setAccountId(mappedAccountId);
        leadConvert.setContactId(mappedContactId); then it is working fine but creating duplicates instead updating the already existing records such as contact and account.